# Tengo graves problemas para solucionar mi codigo, me da error el "InnerHTML", me dice que no esta definido y no lo entiendo

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null  at tablaH, me aparece esto y no logro encontrar una solucion. Alguien me ayuda?

```
function tablaH(array){
    document.querySelector("#tusHeroes").innerHTML=""

    array.forEach(function(elemento){
      let colum=document.createElement('tr')
      colum.classList='text-center'

      let info=`
        <td>${elemento.alias}</td>
        <td>${elemento.nombre}</td>
        <td>${elemento.poder}</td>
        <td>${elemento.equipo}</td>
        <td>${elemento.imagen}</td>
    `
      colum.innerHTML=info

      let base=document.querySelector('#tusHeroes')
      base.appendChild(colum)
        
    });
}

tablaH(heroes)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). En tu caso, faltaría algo de HTML y el contenido de `heroes` para poder reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Parece que tu código busca un elemento con id `tusHeroes` pero no lo encuentra.

Comment: @PabloLozano, tengo en borradores su código funcionando correctamente sin errores. O nos comparte el código completo, o no se puede reproducir su problema. De hecho, voy a iniciar la votación de cierre.